# php how to format a decimal number?

Tags: php, if-statement, compare

I have a number like $amount =  '1,120.01' and I need to compare with an integer (e.g. if($amount < 300) { do this } }. However for some reasons php sees such numbers (1,120.01 or 300.00 ) to have a lower value so I'm wondering how should I format it.

Comment: You can't use commas (thousands separators).

Comment: I assume you mean `$amount = '1,120.01'` (i.e. as a string) right?

Comment: @BenM that's right ! It's about a string .

Comment: Just replace commas with an empty string and cast the result into a (float).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Code to Convert string...As from the ABove

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14482490/627868 Ksg Answer.

```
<?php
$string_number = '1,120.01';

$number = (str_replace(',','',$string_number));

print $number;

?>
```

Comment: So i feel it is as String...Because u mention in your question $amount = '1,120.01' am i right?

Answer (score 0):

You can strip commas from amount and compare like
`if(((float)str_replace(',','',$amount)) < 300)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$amount = '1,120.01';
$amount = format($amount);

if ($amount < 300) {
    echo $amount, " less than 300", PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo $amount, " grater than 300", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
1120.01 grater than 300
```

Function Used

```
function format($number) {
    $places = strlen(substr(strrchr($number, "."), 1));
    $number = filter_var($number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    return $number / pow(10, $places);
}
```